# Copy & Paste Using Drag and Drop With MS VB?

Tags: copy, paste, basic

I'm looking to copy and paste from a windows form. I'm writing this program in Microsoft Visual Basic. I'm stuck. I can't seem to get copy files that have been dragged into the windows form.

I'm Asking for help, As I started 3 months ago with MS VB.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using VB6 then

you can retrieve file names from `Data.Files()` object

```
Private Sub Form_OLEDragDrop(Data As DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    dim fname
    for each fname in Data.Files
        '...
    next 
End Sub
```

don't forget to set OleDropMode property of the form to Manual (1)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual basic 2010. I want to drag data in my window then copy it. ill try your code right now....

Comment: This is garbage. I never got my answer. Remind me not to do this again.